# Is there a way to monitor cpu usage dynamically in charts in asp.net web application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, performancecounter

I tried using performance monitor to identify cpu usage and ram usage in C#. But I am not sure how to monitor these data continuously in web applications in a chart. Can you guys help out please.

Comment: What CPU you are trying to monitor - on the server or client side?

Comment: @Anton: I am trying to get the cpu usage of my asp.net web application.

Comment: Well, any web application has 2 parts. Server and client. To measure server, you need ASP.net methods. On client you need JavaScript methods. But it seems to me, that it is not possible to read CPU information on client.

Comment: Can you show us this code. please?

Comment: Ahh... now better. `PerformanceCounter` is running on server, so you are measuring server's CPU.

Comment: I was checking this link for solving this. It has cpu time and memory usage of a specific asp.net web application. But I am looking for the cpu usage and not time.
https://dzone.com/articles/top-aspnet-performance-counters-and-how-to-monitor